# Is $H\cup K$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ is $H\cup K$ also a subgroup of $G$?

We have identity for sure(since it is in $H$ or $K$), associativity is absorbed.

Thus we only need to see if inverses and closure hold.

I can't see how to test if $hk\in H\cup K$ where $h\in H$, $k\in K$. I can't see why this would be the case. I mean if $h=\langle h\rangle$ , $k=\langle k \rangle$, $h\ne k$ then $hk$ isn't in either cycle right? So this is false?

Comment: You're right. A counterexample is $2\mathbb Z \cup 3\mathbb Z$: 2+3 is not in the set.

Comment: Yes, it's false, in general. You might prove that if $H\cup K$ is a subgroup, then either $H\subseteq K$ or $K\subseteq H$. I'm sure there are several questions here about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you can choose $h\in H, k\in K$ and $h, k \notin H\cap K$

Then if $hk\in K$ you have $hkk^{-1}\in K$ i.e. $h\in K$ so that $h\in H\cap K$, but this contradicts the original choice. Likewise it is a contradiction to have $hk\in H$. This means $hk\notin H \cup K$.

So the only way that $H\cup K$ can be a group is if we can't choose $h,k$ as above, i.e. if one of $H$ or $K$ is a subgroup of the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're right. You have to be careful about how you choose $h$ and $k$ though, or else it could happen that $\langle h \rangle \subset \langle k \rangle$, for instance.

An easier example to think about is the group $\mathbb R^2$ under addition. Then the $x$ and $y$ axes are subgroups, but their union is not a subgroup. This is a classic example from linear algebra showing why the union of subspaces isn't necessarily a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: in $S_3$, let $A=<(123)>$, $B=<(12)>$, consider $A\cup B$.